# GET vs POST - Document generation and download RESTfully

Tags: rest, post, get

I'm writing a RESTful API in which a client can request that a report be generated. The report does not have an ID nor does it exist independently of this request. The report request has a number of parameters: approximately 10 (report type, entity IDs to query, date ranges, other specifiers).

However, it won't be accessed again after the initial download. Should this be a POST request or a GET request? I see the arguments for both but feel like POSTing is more RESTful for a few reasons. Firstly, without the request the report does not exist. Secondly, if we ever decide to add a caching layer this would definitely be a POST as the request has the side effects of creating the report, then we would save a key and return the cached report. However, for now, we aren't doing any caching (though this could change in the future).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `POST` to `/reports` to create the report instance. Return the report representation in the response. You can later choose to store the reports and support `GET`, or not.

If nothing else, I'd say using `GET` violates the principle of least astonishment. In addition, it may constrain future growth of your API.